# Add more vertexes along GeoJSON linestring

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, densify

How can I add more vertex 
Some lines only have two vertices. The problem is on 3D globe it's not dense enough and does not clamp to earth

Does ogr2ogr or OGRINFO support this geospatial operation

Answer (score 1):

You can use QGIS for this quite easily. Simply load in your GeoJSON layer, and use `Vector` > `Geometry Tools` > `Densify geometries`. You can save the output layer as a GeoJSON, which will have added vertices to the layer.

From a quick search, it also seems that there is a function for densifying geometries in the Python GDAL module. If you need a command line tool, you could look into this option. The GitHub repository for the function is [here](https://github.com/postmates/gdal/blob/master/samples/densify.py).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply with ogr2ogr by making a copy by using the -segmentize option http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html.

Example:

Original GeoJSON

```
ogrinfo -al line.json
INFO: Open of `line.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: line
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (40.000000, 160.000000) - (60.000000, 160.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
OGRFeature(line):0
  LINESTRING (40 160,60 160)
```

Create a new densified GeoJSON file so that the distance between vertices is no more than 3 units.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -segmentize 3 densified.json line.json
```

Check the result:

```
ogrinfo -al densified.json
INFO: Open of `densified.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: line
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (40.000000, 160.000000) - (60.000000, 160.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
OGRFeature(line):0
  LINESTRING (40 160,42.8571428571429 160.0,45.7142857142857 160.0,48.5714285714
286 160.0,51.4285714285714 160.0,54.2857142857143 160.0,57.1428571428571 160.0,6
0 160)
```

I do not recommend ogrinfo for this task because it gets too complicated. You can create intermediate points by using ogrinfo with `-sql` and `-dialect SQLite` by utilizing function `Line_Interpolate_Equidistant_Points` https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html but that creates a new multipoint dataset which you should save into new layer and then split the original lines at intersections afterwards.